# Class Diagram in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a Visual Studio like plugin for Eclipse that will allow me create a class-diagram ?

Preferable something that is actually up to date. Most of what Google finds is dead projects who haven't been updated in 2-6 years.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6167414/413032

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

- [Omondo](http://www.uml2.org/)
- [Eclipse Modeling](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=uml2)

Answer (score 2):

You can browse UML plugins [here](http://eclipse-plugins.2y.net/eclipse/plugins.jsp?category=UML).

You can also check [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390438/good-free-uml-tool-for-java-eclipse) stackoverflow questions covering the same topic.

Comment: That list is servere outdated. Notice how the last modified plugin were modified almost 3 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

You could try http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/amaterasuml which is an Eclipse plugin for class diagrams, sequence diagrams and usecase diagrams.  It was updated in 2009.

Answer (score 2):

I like [ObjectAid](http://www.objectaid.com/).

Here is a screenshot (from their homepage) of an example of a class diagrams it can produce:

[image: Class diagram screenshot]
<sub>(source: [objectaid.com](http://www.objectaid.com/images/complete-diagram.png))</sub>

Comment: Perfect! ObjectAid did the job.