# Uml creator for java code

Tags: java, uml

Hi I have 6 java files that I would like to be reversed engineered into a uml design. Right now they are all related by composition and 3 of them are related by inheritance. Do you guys know of any free software that I can use to generate these UML designs automatically?

Comment: were those files created from UML or manually?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390438/good-free-uml-tool-for-java-eclipse

Comment: possible duplicate of [From Java code to UML diagram](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687323/from-java-code-to-uml-diagram)

Comment: ironic now here years later I look this up on google and this is the first result. Not to mention all the questions people linked to are closed.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167266/generate-uml-class-diagram-from-java-project heres a working one for what its worth