# How to create a diagram that explains the flow of my code?

Tags: java, ide

If I'm faced with the task of understanding a new Java application, is there a tool that could analyze the code and come up with a diagram for it?

If analyzing a full application sounds too excessive, how about something that could analyze the flow of code within a handful of classes?

I'm wondering if there's a program or an IDE that can do that. Because a quick diagram of the code will boost my ability to learn the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

http://apwebco.com/gofpatterns/creational/Prototype.html

And also, check this answer out:

[Generate UML Class Diagram from Java Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167266/generate-uml-class-diagram-from-java-project)

Comment: eUML2 from the link you shared nailed it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I used [JDeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/overview/index.html) like year ago for such task. It is really complex IDE and it is really good for (bigger) reverse engeneering. You can read and see more [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/java_class_and_uml_modeling) - blog post by @Shay Shmeltzer

Comment: Is JDeveloper free? Coz I tried to download it before seems like it's looking for an Oracle account. Can I download it from somewhere else?

Comment: @Ernie As far as I remember creating oracle account is free and JDeveloper is also free - quoting from the oracle page : _"Oracle JDeveloper is a **free** integrated development environment that simplifies..."_

Comment: Let me try it, thanks and +1 for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is understand the code and use an UML diagram fore it. You will probably find lots of information like [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/uml/)