# Generate UML graph for whole project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, uml

I have a pretty massive java project to work on (debug and refactor) and I would really like to be able to generate a UML diagram for the whole project in order to be able to see the interactions between the different classes on the fly.
I'm using IntelliJ Idea as an IDE. 
I've been reading the many threads about this in StackOverflow. Mostly they deal with eclipse and not idea and the only tip I found for idea was to use the built-in UML tool, but it doesn't give me the UML diagram to the project scale as I want.

Could you please tell me which tool or plugin you use. That would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try Visual Paradigm, there is an option to import the source code and generate a class diagram. A 30 day free trial is available for you to test it.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That indeed was helpful

Answer (score -1):

This question  is frecuently made, but there is **any** tool that builds the "UML Graph" that you expect. Normally the result you get is a really big graph (unreadable) or a very small grap (useless).

Therefore, what I prefer to do first is doing my own grap using **paper and pencil** while I analize the code by hand. Second, for documentation purposes, I redo this UML diagram using [Dia](https://projects.gnome.org/dia/), which is normaly used by big open source projects, as RichFaces.

Anyway, if you still want to try a magic tool for making your job, see here:

[Generate UML Class Diagram from Java Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167266/generate-uml-class-diagram-from-java-project)

Regards,

Comment: Don't need it to "do my job", just to understand the structure of the project faster no need to be judgmental. Thanks for your tip anyway