# Enterprise Architect Create UML Class Diagram from Code

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram, enterprise-architect

I checked out these here:

- [Generate UML Class Diagram from Java Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167266/generate-uml-class-diagram-from-java-project)
- http://youtu.be/hT_Rs-fOttE
- http://youtu.be/dHrDIsPmtEU

But the very first step in these tutorials, to right-click on class-view and selecting `CodeEngineering->ImportSourceDirectory` fails; `Code Engineering` opens a sub-context-menu containing only `Suppress Namespace`, without `ImportSourceDirectory` option.

What am I doing wrong?
Or is the option in my version of EA (10.0.1005) located somewhere else?

Comment: When you downvote people at least explain why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You either have the wrong EA edition; code engineering is not supported in the desktop edition -> see http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/compare-editions.html to compare the EA editions.
Or you don't have all the menu options enabled, which is a very common problem.
Go to View|Workspaces and commands... select the Command tab and select the complete set. That will enable all menuoptions.

Comment: thank you; I really had the menu options disabled and never suspected this as the problem because the shortcut ctrl+alt+U as described in the manual didn't work either.

Comment: _@Geert Bellekens_ OT: Why didn't you merge your [_old temporary SO user account_](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2045460/user2045460) with this one. You deserve the reputation points, just take them with you. For details read [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts), unless this was intentional.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Thanks, I didn't even know I had another SO user. Both are merged now.

Comment: De nada, I just remembered that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just spent 1 hour not understanding why I didn't have the option!