# create UML classes diagram

Tags: java

I have a project to make; I have a  market and many products, each one has name, date of production, 
etc...
I have made the classes for the project, but I need to make a diagram of the classes, but I don't know how. Also I want to insert customer data in a file like what they buy and the price and each customer can have many purchase cards to buy.
Can any one help me?

```
 class product  implements Cloneable{
     String productName;
     String Description;
     int quantity; 
     product category;

     product(){}
     product(product p){}

     /** Returns a deep clone of this */
     public Object clone() {
         product p = new product();
         return p;
     }

 }

 class Beverage extends product{
     int capacity;

     public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
     }
 }

class  Condiment extends product {
    String country;

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
}

class Dairyproduct extends product  {
    Date  productionDate;
    Date ExpirationDate;
    String  saleUnit;

    public void setProductionDate(Date productionDate) {
        this.productionDate = productionDate;
    }

    public void setExpirationDate(Date ExpirationDate) {
        this.ExpirationDate = ExpirationDate;
    }

    public void setSaleUnit(String saleUnit) {
        this.saleUnit = saleUnit;
    } 
} 

class Customer{
    String Fname;
    String Lname;
    int Id;
    String Address;

    public void setFname(String Fname) {
        this.Fname = Fname;
    }

    public void setLname(String Lname) {
        this.Lname = Lname;
    }

    public void setId(int Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public void setAddress(String Address) {
        this.Address = Address;
    }

 }

 class PurchaseCard{
     Date PurchaseDate;
     LocalDateTime PurchaseTime;
     Map<product,Boolean> PurchasedProducts ;
     double TotalPrice;
 }
```

Comment: IF this is Java code, which it appears to be, you can use an applicaiton called BlueJ which will diagram all your classes automatically.

Comment: This isn't a homework/assignment production center. If you have specific questions, I am sure they can be answered

Comment: You don' t know hiw to make uml class diagrams or how to have them being created from your existing code automagically by some tool?

Comment: For the UML, check out these:
* http://sourceforge.net/projects/code2uml/
* http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/com.soyatec.uml.doc/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate UML Class Diagram from Java Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167266/generate-uml-class-diagram-from-java-project)

Comment: Use draw.io. It's an online tool like visio.

Comment: Thanks you all, but any one can help me more ?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the code and want to generate the class diagram based on that I suggest trying built-in plugins in IDE. IDEA for example can generate class diagram with the dependencies.

If you're thinking of creating schemas upfrom I highly recommend [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/) (they have 30 days trial period and you'll be able to do the customization you need).