# Strategy to separate module from Java project

Tags: java

I'm separating a module from a Java project (essentially creating a separate Java Project for the module). I've been spending a lot of time to figure out the class dependencies. What strategy/tool can I use to help speed up the process?

For example, if I know for sure that I need to extract out class A into the new project, how would I quickly identify all the classes on which class A depends for successful compilation.

#### Approaches tried:

At the moment, I'm going by repetitive cycles of: add required classes to new project -> compile -> gather necessary classes from original project based on compiler error message -> repeat.

Generating UML Class Diagrams is [not working out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6167266/640378) as most UML reverse-engineering tools seem to have some limitation or the other when it comes to identifying inheritance, associations, etc. I already tried ArgoUML.

Comment: try generating a class heirarchy.  Eclispe supports this: I suspect that any IDE will allow you to generate a class heirarchy.

Comment: Sorry, don't really understand your problem. Are you familiar with 'Find usages' in your IDE?

Comment: @ponomandr Find usages gives me the list of classes where my class is being referenced. However, I want the opposite. For example, to compile the `java.util.LinkedList` class, you'd need the `Iterator` class because it is referenced in the `LinkedList` class. Basically, I'd like to identify all such classes (`Iterator`, `ListIterator`, `Collection`, `NoSuchElementException`) referenced in the `LinkedList` class.

Comment: @DwB Class hierarchy in Eclipse simply displays the inheritance structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need "Dependency viewer" of Intellij IDEA.

[image: Intellij IDEA Dependecy viewer]

It can be found under `Analyze > Analalyse Dependecies...`

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Eclipse has the best built-in utilities to get information about class dependencies and such. You could go into the debug view and trace each class and/or method.

Comment: I can't go into the debug view because I'm not even able to compile in the first place.

Comment: Really, any decent Java IDE can do this.  If it can't you're using a niche product.