# Is there a way to generate diagrams from a code in GitHub?

Tags: github, uml, diagram, class-diagram, sequence-diagram

Is there a way to generate diagrams from a code in GitHub ?

Example I want to generate a sequence or class diagram from a code in my GitHub account.

Like generate documentation in Eclipse from a java code

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do `git clone` and then use a tool over the source code e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167266/generate-uml-class-diagram-from-java-project

Comment: @Cratylus this is the answer, you could post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do git clone of the repo you want and then use any tool you prefer over the source code e.g. [Generate UML diagram from java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167266/generate-uml-class-diagram-from-java-project)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of standalone tools that can generate those diagrams (i.e. IDEs like IntelliJ, VStudio enterprise, etc.). For direct GitHub to UML diagrams you can try GitUML online service, the counterpart is that this tool only allows to generate diagrams from 4 files in the free layer, I have not tried the payment layer.

Answer (score 1):

For a beautiful free-for-open-source online solution, see: [GitUML](https://gituml.com/)

But be aware - as of now, a maximum of four classes can be selected in the free plan - this is not practical.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of old thread but I think it's a good option for typescript projects, and who knows, some contributors expand it.

[TsUML](https://github.com/remojansen/TsUML)

Answer (score 1):

Did you hear of `gource` ?
It creates animations like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjUuAuBcoqs

It not only generates the diagram between various pieces of project but how those diagrams evolved over time. It takes a directory tree kind of approach with root directory at centre, so as long as each class is in separate  file it is essentially a UML.

To setup on mac run `brew install gource` or download the .exe if you are on windows download the `.exe` from [here](https://gource.io/).

Then close any git repo and from home directory of the repo just run:

`gource` which will run gource with default options

for custom options you can check the docs [here](https://github.com/acaudwell/Gource#using-gource)